# Facebook OAuth stopped working suddenly using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth

Tags: .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I have an old MVC 4.0 app that uses the Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth library.

The problem started 2 weeks ago when facebook stopped supporting v2.2 of the api.

As I understand the problem, facebook now returns JSON while the code I am using is looking for the data using a form post method.

The call that is failing is below:

```html
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback( string returnUrl ) {
   AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication( Url.Action( "ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl } ) );
   if( !result.IsSuccessful ) {
    return RedirectToAction( "LoginFailed", "Auth", new { reason = "Unable to authenticate with your provider. Please try again." } );
   }
```

Does anyone have a fix that will modify the OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication method to consume json instead of form variables?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: No, I did not...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up skipping the oAuth server side calls all together and used the Facebook Javascript SDK in the end. Not really the answer but it is serving the purpose. You have to verify the token returned to the browser from Facebook when posting the info to your action. For that I used the Facebook .net SDK instead of oAuth. Worked fist try. I hope that helps.